# How to create google instant previews like feature in JSP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, menu

As you know google instant previews is an ajax feature that shows contents of the search results as you move over them by mouse. I want to create something like that, not exactly like that. I have a chart in my page, what I'm trying to do is that when I move mouse over the chart a menu opens and shows some other charts or information. thnx.

Comment: Wether you use JSP or not doesn't matter. This works using JavaScript (and AJAX if you want to load additional info on demand rather than eagerly).

Comment: I know that I can implement it with JS. I'm looking for something like jquery plugin that has already implemented the work.

Comment: Then you should tag your question with jquery and javascript, and not with jsp, google, and menu. But honestly, you don't need a plugin for this. It's just a matter of having an event listener that displays or hides a div.

Comment: well, I can do this with ajax tooltip, as I said I'm looking for a jquery plugin.

Comment: I think it's the one I need. thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [qTip2 (jQuery plugin)](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#ajax) is what you are looking for.

This link will take you to the ajax example of tooltip. You can view source of example, just click the button `View source` (right-top corner of page).